# How to send (and cancel) input events when dealing with buttons in libGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm creating a turn based game where every tile on the battlefield is a separate button. If the player decides to move his character, tiles (buttons) in movement range get highlighted (activated). I also wanted to make the path character would take shown every the cursor enters any tile in the movement range - and I'm not sure how to handle events. I've tried simply sending them to every tile (button) in the path:

```
final int X=i,Y=j;
grid[i][j].addListener(new ClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void enter(InputEvent event,float x,float y,int pointer,Actor fromActor)
    {
        if(isMovementActivated&&!grid[X][Y].isDisabled()&&!isParentActivated)
        {
            isParentActivated=true;
            Tile temp = grid[X][Y];
            while(temp.parent!=null&&temp.parent.isEmpty())
            {
                temp=temp.parent;
                temp.fire(event);
            }
            isParentActivated=false;
        }
      }
}
});
```

(isParentActivated is out there to prevent previous tiles in the path from entering the same part of the code. If I'm right, otherwise they would just send more and more events to the tiles that were already highlighted.
Checking if temp.parent.isEmpty() prevents from highlighting the character itself: it returns true only for tiles that have no obstacles.)

While temp.fire(event) highlights every tile in the path properly, it doesn't cancel the event after it's done. I can't seem to find a way to cancel all events of a listener and "solutions" like creating an InputEvent variable outside of the listener, firing() it for every temp tile and cancelling it when needed - turned out wrong (or my code was just bad; I'm still a beginner, unfortunately).

I COULD just temporarily change the style of buttons in the path: it would contain rolled over image under regular "up" image - so basically it would look like rolled over... without being ACTUALLY rolled over or handling any events at all. But then again, it would be nice to know how to do it properly.

So, my question is: is there a way to easily send events to other buttons and cancel them if needed? Or am I stuck with "dirty" (?) solutions like changing the ButtonStyle each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should use the power of `ImageButtonStyle` to correctly highlight buttons instead of switching styles. Define such [style](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/Skin):

   ```
   "some-button": {
       "imageUp": "default state of button",
       "imageDown": "button is clicked",
       "imageOver": "button with mouse over",
       "imageChecked": "highlighted state (like imageUp but checked)",
       "imageCheckedOver": "highlighted state with mouse over"
   }
   ```

   And call `setChecked(boolean checked)` method of button to make it *highlighted*.
2. It's bad idea to use events in that way. You shouldn't send the event manually, you could call some method instead.

   ```
   ...
   {
       ClickListener clickListener = new ClickListener(){
           @Override
           public void enter(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor fromActor)
           {
              highlightButtons(fromActor);
           }
       }

       grid[i][j].addListener(clickListener);
   }
   ...

   public void highlightButtons(Actor actor)
   {
       // iterate through the buttons and call setChecked of each button should be highlighted 
       // to detect right buttons you could use ArrayMap<ImageButton, YourClass>
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a method like setChecked(boolean checked) all along - while I'm pretty sure I was aware of it, it seems that I didn't know how to manage the styles of buttons properly back then. I solved the issue by changing styles each time I wanted to highlight a button, but your suggestion is much better and I'm definitely trying it out. Thanks a lot.